Как на стороне пользователя обновить .htaccess файл?
Ранее в .htaccess был прописан редирект с категории сайта на главную страницу. Однако теперь данный редирект убрали. В браузере пользователей однако все равно происходит 301 редирект. Можно ли как-то сообщить всем браузерам пользователей об обновлении .htaccess файла, чтобы данный редирект перестал работать у всех пользователей, которые заходят на сайт?

пользователи вообще никак не знают ничего про htaccess файл. Эти перенаправления работают внутри апача. У вас либо есть еще другие правила которые делают схожие редиректы (напоминаю что htaccess обрабатывается  в цикле пока совпадений не останется) либо редирект происходит уже внутри исполняемого кода вэб-приложения.

нет, редирект был только в данном файле. Как только редирект был снят - через инкогнито страница категории была доступна. А просто в браузере редирект еще был.

Никак. Проще всего смириться и поменять адрес новой страницы. Или сообщить всем пользователям что они должны почистить кеш.
